# asp menu highlight when mouse over

Tags: asp.net, html, menu

i currently have the following code for my menu

```
<td><a href="Products.asp?isnew=true"><img height="21" border="0" src="images/productmenu/new_items<%if request.querystring("isnew")="" then%><%else%>_bold<%end if%>.png" width="120"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="Products.asp?category=200 gram"><img height="21" border="0" src="images/productmenu/Shoes<%if trim(lcase(request.querystring("category")))<>"Shoes" then%><%else%>_bold<%end if%>.png" width="120"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="Products.asp?category=360 gram"><img height="21" border="0" src="images/productmenu/Shirts<%if trim(lcase(request.querystring("category")))<>"Shirts" then%><%else%>_bold<%end if%>.png" width="120"></a></td>
```

I would like to add a mouse over for each of these menu items where it calls the appropriate image for example "new_items_highlight.png pic" for the mouse over on the new item menu link.

Can I add an additional statement to my current "if" statement?

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: 1) Don`t use tables for layout. 2) Use CSS class names and backgrounds, not inline images.

Answer (score 0):

Mouseover is a client-side event. You can't handle this on the server side, so you'll need to write some javascript to take care of this for you. Your if statement only determines what the image will be when the page loads.

As Diodeus said in the comments, you could also use CSS for this.

Either way, you'll want to preload the image to prevent flashing.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve what you need with server side code, at least not in "classic" asp.  You will probably be best suited with some javascript to do the mouseovers.  The mouseover event is going to be triggered and handled by the Browser, not the server.  You could put a javascript in there to trigger a server callback on mouseover, but that would be a lot of callbacks and you would have to handle session state in a clumsy way to know what to do.

I would start here:  http://forum.codecall.net/topic/36057-javascripttutorial-mouseover-image-change/#axzz2BNLWbikf

Comment: Using a callback here would also cause a delay/flash when the image is moused over.

Comment: agreed.  server callback is highly discouraged in this situation.  lots of ugly in that.

Comment: I not really good with java so if i used the example shawn gave above what would my html statement be to make these menu items a link as well as 3 differnt images. 1. main image 2. mouse over 3. selected menu item.

Comment: I'm thinking something like the following (pulled from that link):  `<A href="Products.asp?category=200 gram" onmouseover="change('img1')" onmouseout="changeback('img1')"><IMG SRC="main_image.jpg" name="img1" width="100" height="100"></A>`

Answer (score 0):

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/ just try to check this JS plugin, I hope you can figure out something from it..